# What is the psychology behind laying out slabs at different angles for cyclists and pedestrians?

Tags: usability, design, pyschology

In the UK, we have many paths that are shared by pedestrians and cyclists, with a dividing line down the center to show who should be on which side of the path.

I noticed that at the end of such paths there are usually some different coloured slabs with ridges on them. Presumably these are just to alert people that the path is ending.

But I've noticed that on every path, the ridges are arranged differently for the cycle lane to the pedestrian lane- they always go parallel to the path for cylists, and perpendicular for pedestrians.

[image]

There is obviously a reason for this, since it appears to be universally applied. But I can't figure it out. I would have thought that it would make more sense to make the cyclists have the "bumpy" slabs, so they consciously notice that the shared path has now ended. As for pedestrians, I can't see why it should make a difference at all- maybe ridges across the path make it less slippery in the snow?

Can anyone suggest the actual reason?

Comment: Why should the cyclists be alerted that they're on the correct side of the road?

Comment: @Juhana So they don't rush round a blind corner on the wrong side of the path and crash into an old lady.

Comment: Sorry to ask a tangential question, but is that a two way path? Are both directions of cyclists really expected to share half the path? Seems awkward...

Comment: @SteveBennett Yes it is two way. Not such a problem for pedestrians, but cylists have to watch out for other cyclists coming the other way.

Comment: Cool - but weird. Paths here (Australia) are split down the middle, for direction, like a road. Pedestrians and cyclists share space.

Comment: In-line ridges are dangerous for cyclists. It is safer to ride the bumpy side, therefore this "deterrent" is counter productive. In-line ridges cause loss of traction if you're not perfectly aligned, and considering these are often used on approach to corners (where a cyclist is turning on approach) they will cause the front wheel to slip away. Add ice to the mix and you're screwed.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It's not psychology; it's purely physical.

The reason is that the perpendicular ridges are easy for pedestrians to walk on, but bumpy for cyclists; and the in-line ridges are easy for cyclists and harder for pedestrians.

Note that this is at the entry of the cycle lane. It's not designed to alert cyclists that their lane is **ending;** it's designed to make sure that cyclists do not **enter** the pedestrian lane (and that pedestrians do not enter the cycle lane).

You can see a similar thing at UK level crossings — there are triangular sections laid with a point upwards in this photo. They are difficult to walk along and make access to the tracks difficult.

[image: UK level crossing access restrictor]

The in-line ridges in the cycle-path are not as ankle-crushingly difficult, but make the point while being easy for cyclists to ride between.

<sub>Image: Lincoln High Street from the [Lincolnshire Echo](http://www.thisislincolnshire.co.uk/Footbridge-plans-level-crossings-Lincoln-revealed/story-15578579-detail/story.html)</sub>

Comment: I'm not convinced the in-line ridges make any difference to pedestrians - I've never noticed any - but the perpendicular ridges are unpleasant to cycle over.

Comment: In-line ridges are dangerous for cyclists, not easier. If the pitch is sufficiently wide, it can catch a tire.

Comment: Actually, it does let them know they are leaving the lane: "This lets people know they are entering or leaving the route." and "[the surface] should extend to a depth of 2400mm. For the repeater strips, however, only 800mm depth of 
surface is required." ([Source](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/3622/tactile-pavement.pdf)). So the strips delimiting the shared area should be 3 times deeper.

Comment: @JackAidley These markers are not there for general pedestrians or cyclists. They are there as tactile feedback for partially sighted users (who can't read the signage).

Comment: @Brendon: Do you have a source for that claim?

Comment: @Brendon: In fact, "This arrangement was chosen because it was felt the rumble effect created by the transverse pattern 
would deter cyclists from entering on the pedestrian side." from [here](http://bit.ly/11qf63j) (pdf link) on page 55. I think this refutes your claim that they are purely for partially sighted users.

Comment: One more thing; not all cyclists ride road-style bikes (with narrow slick or grooved tires) for which the perpendicular grooves would prove uncomfortable. Cruiser, trail or full mountain-bike style frames and wheels would eat the slab on the right of the OP's image for breakfast.

Comment: I’m with Kaz: when cycling I routinely drive onto the pedestrians’ half to avoid the in-line ridges.

Comment: The uncomfortable looking triangles that keep walkers off the rail tracks are brilliant.

Comment: @JackAidley Well, I don't think this system would be used if partially sighted people didn't exist. The entire design is driven by the needs of partially sighted users. The fact that the horizontal rumble strips deter cyclists seems rather peripheral to the design.

Comment: As a road bike cyclist, I am cautious about riding over anything that could cause pulling and would switch to the pedestrian side of the slabs, especially when the road is wet. Riding over the slabs vertically minimizes the occurring forces.

Comment: The triangle strips would last about a half hour in the US, until the very first person fell and hurt themselves badly on them. Why does the UK seem to delight in creating scary, dangerous things?

Answer (score 17):

Not sure if this is the primary reason, but it can help partially sighted users.

Tactile surfaces are used in the UK to provided information about the environment to partially sighted people. For example "blister" surface is to warm people that a footpath is ending and a carriageway begining.

Further information can be found here: https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/3622/tactile-pavement.pdf

Comment: In the document you will find information about the tactile path marking described in the question: Chapter 5 - Segregated Shared Cycle Track/Footway Surface and Central
Delineator Strip

Comment: It's also described in [The Highway Code rule 13](https://www.gov.uk/rules-pedestrians-1-to-35/crossing-the-road-7-to-17): "Segregated routes may also incorporate short lengths of tactile paving to help visually impaired people stay on the correct side. On the pedestrian side this will comprise a series of flat-topped bars running across the direction of travel (ladder pattern). On the cyclist side the same bars are orientated in the direction of travel (tramline pattern)."

Answer (score 8):

This is a physical alert for cyclist not to enter pedestrain lane. Such physical alerts used also on the roads for [good vibrations](http://online.wsj.com/article/SB122469915344259035.html).
[image]

Comment: Cyclists don't like riding across the unpleasant bumps.  When they do, it's a good indicator that they are doing something wrong.  Assuming they are aware of the system that is.

Answer (score 7):

These differences in tactile surfaces are physical guidances for visually impaired users of shared cyclist/pedestrian paths that aren't otherwise differentiated. e.g. by use of railing, curbs or levels

Additionally, local government installations of these surface are guided by or consulted with the Department of Transport so they are, therefore universally applied.

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be for visualy impaired people. The orientation of the ridges must be a convention.

I think that it is badly chosen in this case : The perpendicular ridges are harder to guess with a stick for blind people (they move it from left to right). And the others are quite dangerous for bikes when wet because tires could get trapped in gutters. If the bike is not ridding straight, it may make the driver fall.

Comment: I agree with the bike-slabs looking a tad dangerous as they could force the side-to-side position of a wheel and prevent the rider to make balancing steers.

Answer (score 6):

Jack Aidley linked to the Government document [Guidance on the use of tactile paving surfaces](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/3622/tactile-pavement.pdf) in a comment to another answer, but he missed the salient point in the document which directly addresses this question.

> ## 5.1 Purpose
>
> - The purpose of the tactile surface used in conjunction with a segregated shared cycle track/footway is to **advise visually impaired people of the correct side to enter**.

*emphasis mine*

May I also add that as a father who pushes a buggy around, I always use the cycle-side when entering and leaving these paths!

Comment: Could they just learn to walk to the right, instead of having to change the paving all over the country?

Comment: @nocomprende There's no consistency as to which side is which.

Comment: "Walk on the right" is always walk on the right. How in the world could they create a system without a consistent traffic rule? That's crazy.

Comment: @nocomprende The guidance says councils should lay new paths out that way., but it's only guidance not law. Many old paths pre-date the guidance anyway.